# Should I call loadAd at anytime I want in Admob?

Tags: admob

I need to show a ad when it is over in my game.And I am not sure if I should call loadAd() everytime I want or just once when admob was inited?
Anyone could help me about this? thx

Answer (score 0):

### Load FullScreen Admob

```
-(void)loadFullScreen
{
    AdmobFullScreen=[[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    AdmobFullScreen.delegate=self;
    AdmobFullScreen.adUnitID=@"YourID";
    [AdmobFullScreen loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

-(void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    [AdmobFullScreen presentFromRootViewController:self];
}

-(void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}
```

In this way just call above method when require fullscreen admob

More Information to provide http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-admob-integrate-in-your-application-in-iphone/